# Does database caching policy apply to all of the tables in the database in Azure Data Explorer/ Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

A kusto database has caching policy of 7 days and  but when I check the caching policy of the particular table in that same database , it shows null. Does this mean that that table is hot data cache? Or does the child entities(tables) of the entity(database) inherit same caching policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tables in the database inherit the caching policy of the database, unless the policy is explicitly overridden at the table level.

Answer (score 3):

plus - when in doubt, you can use `.show tables details` to see the *effective* caching policy of tables in a database (that aggregates both database-level & table-level policies, if defined)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-table-details-command